# Splitting existing repository & applying latest commits to another repository

Tags: git, mercurial, repository, dvcs

Some time ago I have converted my SVN repository into Mercurial repository. It seemed to be converted properly and I have already committed many changes to the project. After a while (when digging in the history) I have realized that the conversion was not done properly - i.e old commits were not sorted by time, so I have all the revisions from SVN repository but not in a proper order (and on top of that I have my commits made after the conversion).

I would like to fix this. The only way of fixing this I can think of is to split the repository in two

- one containing revisions converted from old SVN repository (let's call it `A1`)
- and one containing only new commits (let's call it `B1`)

I would like to convert my SVN repository once again (properly this time) and then re-apply all the changes that was made by me since the repository was converted first time (`B1` part).

Just to sum everything up, what I need to do (or, what I think I need to do) is:

1. Split existing repo in two - one piece that was created by converting from SVN repository (`A1`), and the other piece that contains proper commits (made by me after the repository conversion - `B1`).
2. Convert SVN repository to Mercurial (or Git, if for some reason all the other steps are not doable in Mercurial). So after the conversion I will have `A2`.
3. Apply the changes from `B1` to the newly converted repository from point 2 - `A2`

I think I know how to do the conversion (point 2) to get properly ordered commits (`A2`). I just need help with 1. (splitting existing repository into `A1` & `B1`) & 3 (applying commits from `B1` to `A2`).

Is that doable in Mercurial? If it is not doable in Mercurial - is it possible to achieve it using Git (as far as I know it is possible to convert SVN and Mercurial repository to Git repository with ease).

Answer (score 2):

I guess the new changesets are fairly linear. If they are, you can easily do this with MQ. You just need to convert all of the new changesets to MQ changesets (`qimport`), then apply the bunch on top of the freshly converted repository.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting having a deeper look at MQ - I haven't used it very extensively so far.

Answer (score 2):

The [`convert` extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) can also help if you want to create a new repository based on a subset of your existing repository.

Comment: I've used convert before to get rid of binary files (and removing them from history as well). I understand that using `--rev` switch I may convert Mercurial repository into another Mercurial repository with limited number of revisions. 1. how do I re-apply commits from such a repo to another repo? 2. How do I extract only bunch of the very latest commits (so newest, not oldest)?

Comment: Would the `-splicemap` [option](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--splicemap) help?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `strip` command (which is part of the [mq extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension)) to strip out all your new changesets.  This will create a bundle of all the new changesets (the command will output the location of the bundle command).  You should be able to take this bundle and unbundle it (using the `unbundle` command) into the replacement `A2` repository.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting `strip`. I will have a look at it.